# Python ошибка python -u Traceback (most recent call last):?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
python -u
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lea27\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 1, in
\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442
NameError: name '\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442' is not defined
```

Не могу вывести даже простейшие команды типа

```
print ("Привет мир")
```

При

```
print ("Hello World")
```

все работает нормально

Comment: Пожалуйста, когда вы хотите от нас помощь, **постарайтесь не вводить нас в заблуждение.** Ошибка говорит, что имя `Привет` неопределенно, и это *не имеет никакой связи с командой* `pyton -u` (находящейся непосредственно перед выводом ошибки). — Пожалуйста, исправите ваш вопрос в соответствии с тем, что вы видите на вашем экране .

Comment: По обсуждению в комментариях к удаленному ответу: вы написали, что используете расширение Code Runner для запуска из vscode. Вероятно, проблема именно в нем. Для запуска Python кода из vscode это расширение не нужно, отключите или удалите его, используйте просто запуск через расширение Python ([ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)).